# MongoDB on Docker for Windows ~ Export/Import Data

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying to set up an easy-to-use workflow for people in my company to set up a MongoDB Database on Windows, and enable them to exchange their databases as needed.

One impediment here is the need to use Docker Volumes for this, which is currently my greatest issue with exporting and importing data.

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: "3"
services:
    mongoDB:
        image: mongo:4.0.4
        container_name: "mongo_database"
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=test_database
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root_username
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_password
        volumes:
            - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
            - mongo_database_volume:/data/db
        ports:
            - "27017-27019:27017-27019"
volumes:
    mongo_database_volume:
```

I have been able to enter data there and successfully export what I believe to be the database from there using the following command:

```
docker cp mongo_database:/data/db ./_backup
```

This created a folder "db_backup" next to the docker-compose.yml, the contents of which I believe to be the encoded database contents.

I then changed some data, exported it again to a different folder, and tried importing the old database again with what I believe to be the reverse of above command:

```
docker cp "./db_backup" mongo_database:/data/db
```

My expectation was that after this the changed values would go back to their originals in the database.

However, sadly, the changed values were still changed. The import had evidently failed.

So I tried this, after renaming the local folder `db_backup` to `db`:

```
Docker cp ./db mongo_database:/data/
```

Which did something, namely frag the MongoDB. The container crashed instantly, and after trying to re-run it, I got the following exciting error message:

```
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:33.984+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1579880913:984049][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000007: handle-open: open: No such file or directory Raw: [1579880913:984049][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000007: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:33.984+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1579880913:984105][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __wt_txn_recover, 740: Recovery failed: No such file or directory Raw: [1579880913:984105][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __wt_txn_recover, 740: Recovery failed: No such file or directory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:33.990+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880913:990629][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 384: cache server: exiting with 2 pages in memory and 0 pages evicted Raw: [1579880913:990629][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 384: cache server: exiting with 2 pages in memory and 0 pages evicted
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:33.990+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880913:990699][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 389: cache server: exiting with 20549 image bytes in memory Raw: [1579880913:990699][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 389: cache server: exiting with 20549 image bytes in memory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:33.990+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880913:990709][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 393: cache server: exiting with 22853 bytes in memory Raw: [1579880913:990709][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 393: cache server: exiting with 22853 bytes in memory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:33.990+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880913:990715][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 400: cache server: exiting with 22642 bytes dirty and 1 pages dirty Raw: [1579880913:990715][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 400: cache server: exiting with 22642 bytes dirty and 1 pages dirty
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.046+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1579880914:46221][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000007: handle-open: open: No such file or directory Raw: [1579880914:46221][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000007: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.046+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1579880914:46278][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __wt_txn_recover, 740: Recovery failed: No such file or directory Raw: [1579880914:46278][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __wt_txn_recover, 740: Recovery failed: No such file or directory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.070+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880914:70413][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 384: cache server: exiting with 2 pages in memory and 0 pages evicted Raw: [1579880914:70413][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 384: cache server: exiting with 2 pages in memory and 0 pages evicted
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.070+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880914:70474][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 389: cache server: exiting with 20549 image bytes in memory Raw: [1579880914:70474][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 389: cache server: exiting with 20549 image bytes in memory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.070+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880914:70484][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 393: cache server: exiting with 22853 bytes in memory Raw: [1579880914:70484][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 393: cache server: exiting with 22853 bytes in memory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.070+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880914:70490][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 400: cache server: exiting with 22642 bytes dirty and 1 pages dirty Raw: [1579880914:70490][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 400: cache server: exiting with 22642 bytes dirty and 1 pages dirty
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.124+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1579880914:124339][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000007: handle-open: open: No such file or directory Raw: [1579880914:124339][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/journal/WiredTigerLog.0000000007: handle-open: open: No such file or directory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.124+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (2) [1579880914:124399][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __wt_txn_recover, 740: Recovery failed: No such file or directory Raw: [1579880914:124399][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], txn-recover: __wt_txn_recover, 740: Recovery failed: No such file or directory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.133+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880914:133924][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 384: cache server: exiting with 2 pages in memory and 0 pages evicted Raw: [1579880914:133924][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 384: cache server: exiting with 2 pages in memory and 0 pages evicted
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.133+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880914:133975][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 389: cache server: exiting with 20549 image bytes in memory Raw: [1579880914:133975][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 389: cache server: exiting with 20549 image bytes in memory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.133+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880914:133984][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 393: cache server: exiting with 22853 bytes in memory Raw: [1579880914:133984][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 393: cache server: exiting with 22853 bytes in memory
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.133+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (0) [1579880914:133990][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 400: cache server: exiting with 22642 bytes dirty and 1 pages dirty Raw: [1579880914:133990][1:0x7fee5b2c5a40], connection: __wt_cache_destroy, 400: cache server: exiting with 22642 bytes dirty and 1 pages dirty
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.135+0000 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.135+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28559 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 65
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.135+0000 F -        [initandlisten]
mongo_database |
mongo_database | ***aborting after fassert() failure
mongo_database |
mongo_database |
mongo_database | 2020-01-24T15:48:34.144+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
mongo_database |  0x55793a34daa1 0x55793a34ccb9 0x55793a34d19d 0x7fee59a4a390 0x7fee596a4428 0x7fee596a602a 0x557938982ea7 0x557938a79eb3 0x557938a51161 0x557938a5711f 0x557938a39149 0x5579391223a2 0x557938906251 0x5579389ee94b 0x557938984a39 0x7fee5968f830 0x5579389ecab9
mongo_database | ----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
mongo_database | {"backtrace":[{"b":"557937F73000","o":"23DAAA1","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"23D9CB9"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"23DA19D"},{"b":"7FEE59A39000","o":"11390"},{"b":"7FEE5966F000","o":"35428","s":"gsignal"},{"b":"7FEE5966F000","o":"3702A","s":"abort"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"A0FEA7","s":"_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"B06EB3","s":"_ZN5mongo17wtRCToStatus_slowEiPKc"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"ADE161","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"AE411F","s":"_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mbbbb"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"AC6149"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"11AF3A2","s":"_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"993251"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"A7B94B","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"A11A39","s":"main"},{"b":"7FEE5966F000","o":"20830","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"557937F73000","o":"A79AB9","s":"_start"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "4.0.4", "gitVersion" : "f288a3bdf201007f3693c58e140056adf8b04839", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.19.76-linuxkit", "version" : "#1 SMP Thu Oct 17 19:31:58 UTC 2019", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "557937F73000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "955496FB361B86CAB5A87FD0A0E11190E01CE1BF" }, { "b" : "7FFF8E341000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B75FC78C250AED65F3D9722A8F5CBB07C9B34728" }, { "b" : "7FEE5AE49000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E2D1DB1857AE8F07908959381751796E89FF56BB" }, { "b" : "7FEE5AC2E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6EF73266978476EF9F2FD2CF31E57F4597CB74F8" }, { "b" : "7FEE5A7EA000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "250E875F74377DFC74DE48BF80CCB237BB4EFF1D" }, { "b" : "7FEE5A581000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "513282AC7EB386E2C0133FD9E1B6B8A0F38B047D" }, { "b" : "7FEE5A37D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8CC8D0D119B142D839800BFF71FB71E73AEA7BD4" }, { "b" : "7FEE5A175000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "89C34D7A182387D76D5CDA1F7718F5D58824DFB3" }, { "b" : "7FEE59E6C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DFB85DE42DAFFD09640C8FE377D572DE3E168920" }, { "b" : "7FEE59C56000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7FEE59A39000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CE17E023542265FC11D9BC8F534BB4F070493D30" }, { "b" : "7FEE5966F000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B5381A457906D279073822A5CEB24C4BFEF94DDB" }, { "b" : "7FEE5B0B8000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D7B6259552275A3C17BD4C3FD05F5A6BF40CAA5" }, { "b" : "7FEE5943C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E09D3783AD1D0BBCD3204FA01E4EF6D756E18F57" }, { "b" : "7FEE59220000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D1CC1204D6B6D33BD1D2C5A2A0516A2234322CF" }, { "b" : "7FEE58FD6000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DB5180B568097E2A4690A5B40D36BD134C893FEE" }, { "b" : "7FEE58DC7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D3B183C41F02C7CD18F906AAFD19C69C850F1CEB" }, { "b" : "7FEE58B76000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DA0EC53E16B3AC6BDC56EAEFE1BFECDDC395FB2E" }, { "b" : "7FEE5895C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8D9BD4CE26E45EF16075C67D5F5EEAFD8B562832" }, { "b" : "7FEE5862C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3CE893F6D1382C2C7648DCCB06E71B1C7E0861CC" }, { "b" : "7FEE583F9000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B11678F560199547DCF726384EA39153EE0DFABF" }, { "b" : "7FEE581C3000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D6B36C5A463EE0FA84FDD6D5FD3F7726EDB90D54" }, { "b" : "7FEE57F43000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7B3533D5998D20EE1A1BE3F87789B69041E7F620" }, { "b" : "7FEE57C71000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "16E3DBC6D048145939BB43BBFD7954D27421B00F" }, { "b" : "7FEE57A42000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "AEB4C08FC47F86C475E9D3996DFE5E9B403ACEBF" }, { "b" : "7FEE5783E000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1E16CB57F699E215A2A8D4EFEF90883BC749B12D" }, { "b" : "7FEE57633000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DF3219B89E86920E901BAC4A80AA60F2B6134588" }, { "b" : "7FEE57418000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "87783DF8A1058CD150F8886CB36340384093C18F" }, { "b" : "7FEE571D7000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "1FE877BE52A424D0636AFD4D35BB330E41D6E0F3" }, { "b" : "7FEE56F73000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A0E2D03FF5CF65937F4425D4EFD4D655243809EB" }, { "b" : "7FEE56D60000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E07E186694852D8F69459C6AB28A53F8DA3CE3B6" }, { "b" : "7FEE56B5C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3364D4BF2113C4E8D17EF533867ECC99A53413D6" }, { "b" : "7FEE56953000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "73A8EADBC85860662B24850E71D4AFBE22C33359" }, { "b" : "7FEE566C9000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "59E742306A4EA2872E061ECCE92F35FADDA75357" }, { "b" : "7FEE56427000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E5C159E415406AE79D21056D752BA949C408B5B1" }, { "b" : "7FEE561F4000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7D15576E1F096614D360784E4A01A1F5FAF908C9" }, { "b" : "7FEE55FDE000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "481DB33C28D88E43DA6BED65E1A7599407D4D818" }, { "b" : "7FEE55DD6000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9D9C958F1F4894AFEF6AECD90D1C430EA29AC34F" }, { "b" : "7FEE55BAD000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "57E25072866B2D30CF02EBE7AE623B84F96FA700" }, { "b" : "7FEE5599E000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F6F1B4E9F89B716C4A0BA5819BDFFAF4A13EFB91" }, { "b" : "7FEE55753000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C60082E3BB78D0D42868D9B359B89BF66CE5A1A7" }, { "b" : "7FEE5547E000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D9782BA023CAEC26B15D8676E3A5D07B55E121EF" }, { "b" : "7FEE55246000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "7BDD51353D50310FFA1587E4AA01B40ABE32D582" } ] }}
mongo_database |  mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x55793a34daa1]
mongo_database |  mongod(+0x23D9CB9) [0x55793a34ccb9]
mongo_database |  mongod(+0x23DA19D) [0x55793a34d19d]
mongo_database |  libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7fee59a4a390]
mongo_database |  libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0x7fee596a4428]
mongo_database |  libc.so.6(abort+0x16A) [0x7fee596a602a]
mongo_database |  mongod(_ZN5mongo32fassertFailedNoTraceWithLocationEiPKcj+0x0) [0x557938982ea7]
mongo_database |  mongod(_ZN5mongo17wtRCToStatus_slowEiPKc+0x413) [0x557938a79eb3]
mongo_database |  mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngine15_openWiredTigerERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_+0x2D1) [0x557938a51161]
mongo_database |  mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_PNS_11ClockSourceES8_mbbbb+0x63F) [0x557938a5711f]
mongo_database |  mongod(+0xAC6149) [0x557938a39149]
mongo_database |  mongod(_ZN5mongo23initializeStorageEngineEPNS_14ServiceContextENS_22StorageEngineInitFlagsE+0x552) [0x5579391223a2]
mongo_database |  mongod(+0x993251) [0x557938906251]
mongo_database |  mongod(_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_+0x10DB) [0x5579389ee94b]
mongo_database |  mongod(main+0x9) [0x557938984a39]
mongo_database |  libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF0) [0x7fee5968f830]
mongo_database |  mongod(_start+0x29) [0x5579389ecab9]
mongo_database | -----  END BACKTRACE  -----
mongo_database exited with code 14
```

So, obviously, I've done something very wrong here. I just don't know what went wrong.

Can anyone tell me what the correct way to export/import MongoDB databases from Docker Containers on Windows is? A typical use case for us would be to have a selection of different test databases that we want to exchange as the situation demands.

Comment: Hi, I'm also interested to solve this, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I eventually managed to get to work. It's not really what I hoped for, more of a workaround, but I guess it's better than nothing, and maybe this will help some people.

I ended up using MongoDB Compass to do the backups. If the container is correctly configured, you can connent to it from the outside with MongoDB Compass, and then use MongoDB Compass to export databases to a file and later import them.